# Sticky - Featured Image

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I want to change the CSS for all featured images on the index, **except** the sticky post featured image.

Any idea how I can do that?

Currently I have this on the functions file.

```
function ct_chosen_sticky_post_marker() {

if ( is_sticky() && ! is_archive() ) {
    echo '<div class="sticky-status"><span>' . __( "Featured 
Project", "chosen" ) . '</span></div>';
   }
}
add_action( 'sticky_post_status', 'ct_chosen_sticky_post_marker' );
```

And this php on my home page.

```
<?php do_action( 'sticky_post_status' ); ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what the problem you're getting is? E.g. are your sticky posts not getting shown is your css not getting applied to no posts/all posts? Its not clear what you are asking, so we don't know what to help with!

Comment: Have you used the `post_class` and `body_class` functions? All the CSS classes necessary to do this should already be there if you've built your theme correctly

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I had serious health issues... maybe I wasn't clear enough, let me try again: I want to change the height of the featured image, which I am able to do via CSS. The problem is that I want to have a different CSS for the featured image of the sticky post. But I do not know how to do that.